# spring cloud config best practice?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

For the spring based project, for example, there are eureka config(eureka.properties), zuul config(zuul.properties), feign config(feign.properties) etc..

And also there are multiple environments like dev, test, staging, like application-dev.properties, application-prod.properties.

After introduced the spring cloud config to the project, we can keep all the config file to the git repo, but how to organize those config files well? and minimize the spring cloud client project's config?

Comment: The same rules for loading environment specific properties (i.e. `application.properties` and `application-[profile].properties`) apply to the properties loaded from the config server. It also applies to `bootstrap.properties` and `bootstrap-[profile].properties`...

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, for the different env, it can use the application-[profile].properties approach, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I misunderstood the spring cloud config at the beginning, with [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/2.1.x/multi/multi__quick_start.html#_client_side_usage)

> The HTTP service has resources in the form:
>
> ```
> /{application}/{profile}[/{label}]
> /{application}-{profile}.yml
> /{label}/{application}-{profile}.yml
> /{application}-{profile}.properties
> /{label}/{application}-{profile}.properties
> ```
>
> where the "application" is injected as the spring.config.name in the > SpringApplication (i.e. what is normally "application" in a regular Spring Boot > app), "profile" is an active profile (or comma-separated list of properties), and > "label" is an optional git label (defaults to "master".)

With the spring cloud config built-in mechanism, the spring cloud config will expose all the properties as the REST resources, so where:

- **application** is the spring boot client project `spring.application.name`
- **profile** is the `spring.profiles.active` in the spring boot client project
- **label** is the git branch name where git git repo is specific by the spring cloud config server , e.g. `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri`

Then the client can `GET` all the properties against the rules above.

Normally for a spring boot client project, just need to config the spring cloud config server like:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: eureka
  cloud:
    config: 
      uri: http://localhost:8888
  profiles:
    active: dev, prod
```

So the client will `GET` all the properties: `eureka-dev.yml` and `eureka-prod.yml` in the spring cloud config server.